# How can I find a variable or specific parts of the sourcecode from websites in C#

Tags: c#

I want to try something out and for that I would want to get a variable / part of the sourcecode in C# and display it. For example on a youtube page every ** seconds get the sourcecode of the page and display the subscriber count.
I don't know if it works, but if, then how? I looked through many different pages on the internet and never found something :/
Thanks!

Comment: Try [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/)

Comment: there are multiple way of doing it, first look if that site provide an API, parsing someone site is illegal without permission.  Youtube provide API for such thing. If you still want to do parsing the above suggested pack is good or any use any HTML/DOM parser to get the data you need.

Comment: You can easily get the HTML of a webpage -- Ctrl-S on most browsers.  That will include Javascript or similar on the page.  It won't include any background program that generated the page.  What part of the 'program' do you want and why?

Comment: @SumitGupta: *"parsing someone site is illegal without permission."*, it certainly isn't illegal. Otherwise how would your web browser work? It might be against TOS and the site in question might block you, but it's not illegal.

Comment: Selenium, AgilityPack and iMacros can be used to scrape with C#

Comment: @MattBurland Try to parse craiglist, they are famous to do drag people to court for parsing and they won it a lot of time. Web browser are why we build site, but if you parse your competitor site or other site and extract data, is breach of most site's TOS, and when it is that case it is illegal. Some build their site for parsing, but not all. Most of business site will block or don't like automate bots to take data from their site. Using API is right way of doing it.